# How to create a JSON rest webservice in php without using any library?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web-services, json

I want to create a hello world json rest webservice in test.php:

```
  <?php header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");


     $test[] = "hello";  
     $test[] = "world";  

    $json = json_encode($test);
    echo $json;    
  ?>
```

But nothing is returned when I test it with ajax below why ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function test()
{ 
    var xhr; 
    try {  xhr = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');   }
    catch (e) 
    {
        try {   xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');    }
        catch (e2) 
        {
          try {  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();     }
          catch (e3) {  xhr = false;   }
        }
     }

    xhr.onreadystatechange  = function()
    { 
         if(xhr.readyState  == 4)
         {
              if(xhr.status  == 200) 
                  alert(xhr.responseText); 
              else 
                 alert("Error code " + xhr.status);
         }
    }; 

   xhr.open(GET, "test.php",  true); 
   xhr.send(null); 
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
test();
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Why you don't use jQuery or other library?

Comment: Because I want to learn the basics first (json + xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 1):

1. You have spaces before your PHP code starts, so the `header` call will error
2. You're setting a `text/html` Content-Type for JSON data, it should be `application/json`
3. You are are replacing the reference to the input element in the form with a string, you probably want to set it's `.value` property instead. (For that matter, you should probably be accessing it as `document.forms.id_of_form.elements.dyn.value` for clarity) (Using an `input` to display output is a rather dubious practice in the first place though)

Comment: I have taken into account 1 & 2. Instead of 3 I just want to show alert but it doesn't work.